# SQlite strftime Query Isuue

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT * 
FROM BillData 
WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%d-%m-%Y','2020-05-04') AND strftime('%d-%m-%Y','2020-07-08')
```

Query Result-it picks date Where the year is 2019

```
SN        Date                                                                                                 
1       07-07-2020                                      
2       07-06-2020                            
3       07-01-2020                      
4       08-07-2020                                              
5       08-07-2019 <------------(return this result 2019)need a solution
```

for this issue

Comment: Seems like your date format is wrong, you set it to be day on the first place, but you pass the date where the year is first. Try `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2020-05-04')`.

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Use a format that matches the date,

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2020-05-04')
```

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM BillData 
WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2020-05-04') AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2020-07-08') no result found(result set is empty)